# Function mail() PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I need someone to help me: I'm trying to use PHP mail() function but it's not working. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 (I'm really newbie at servers) with IIS 7. This is how I've configurated SMTP (Port 25 is opened):

```
Deliver e-mailto SMTP server:
    SMTP server:
    smtp.1and1.es
    Port: 25
    Authentication settings:
    Not required.
```

I've configurated php.ini that way:

```
[mail function] 
;For Win32 only. 
SMTP = smtp.1and1.es 
smtp_port = 25 
;For Win32 only. 
sendmail_from = formphp@mydomain.com
```

my code is this:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$to = 'contact@mydomain.com'; 

if (mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($message))){ 
    echo "Sent"; 
} else { 
    echo "Error"; 
};
```

I always get 'Error'...Is there something I am missing??
I would appreciate any help. Thanxs so much.

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? It should give you a detailed message. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: This is what I get: 30719

Comment: @Pekka웃 means, did you get any error messages on screen after you pasted error_reporting in your code?

Comment: Cross link to a topic with the same error message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944631/could-not-instantiate-mail-function-why-this-error-occuring

Comment: No, I don't get any error, just not sending the e-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this standard php mailer class . Will help you lot.
And easily can configured with any of your domain.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I'm always getting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Answer (score 0):

You have Authentication settings:Not required.   But, doesn't smtp.1and1.es require authentication?

Comment: You're right, I've changed it but still doesn't send the e-mail

Comment: Are providing your username and password for smtp.1and1.es?