# PHPMailer stop working: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a script that sends an email at the end of work. At some point, stop sending messages with an error:

> Could not instantiate mail function

No changes in the script or in the system settings have been made.
The only thing that has changed - increased memory consumption and execution time as the increased volume of data being processed.

Could error associated with memory? If I try to send a message at the beginning of the script, everything works.

**EDIT:**
The same code works at the beginning of the script and is doesn't work at the end.

```
    require_once 'class_phpmailer.php';

    $phpmail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $phpmail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
    $phpmail->Sender = "my@site.com";
    $phpmail->From = "my@site.com";
    $phpmail->FromName = "mysite";
    $phpmail->AddAddress('another@site.com');
    $phpmail->Subject = 'test';
    $phpmail->MsgHTML('test');
    if( !$phpmail->Send() ){
        echo $phpmail->ErrorInfo ;  
    }
```

Comment: This question has been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944631/could-not-instantiate-mail-function-why-this-error-occuring), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function?lq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648462/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function?lq=1). Might want to check out duplicates.

Comment: I read all the threads, the error is the same, but nothing similar to my case

Comment: Just an idea, you never know :-) Don't think it's a memory-issue, most likely you would've gotten a specific error-message in that case. Perhaps sharing your code would help in troubleshooting. @user451555

Comment: I added code to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `php` memory on runtime by adding this script at the top of your mailing page:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Adjust the `16M`

Comment: Limit enough after an error the script is still running for some time and is completed without error associated with memory and execution time.