# PHP form submission error

Tags: php, forms

I created new inquiry form for my website. But it's giving the following error message.

```
Error
Sorry there was an error sending your form.
mail:Could not instantiate mail function.
```

Form HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>PHP Contact Form Script With Validation - reusable form</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" >
        <script src="form.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h2>Contact Us</h2> 
                    <p> Send us your message and we will get back to you as soon as possible </p>
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label for="name"> First Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label for="name"> Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label for="email"> Phone:</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                <label for="name"> Message:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Post It! </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3> </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Handler.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['firstname','lastname', 'email','phone'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);




$pp->sendEmailTo('name@mail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not instantiate mail function. Why this error occurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944631/could-not-instantiate-mail-function-why-this-error-occurring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmailer error “Could not instantiate mail function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function)

Comment: you are missing action in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining an action for the form.

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" action="Handler.php">
    <!-- html goes here -->
</form>
```