# PHPMailer script working Hostinger not on fatcow

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a PHPMailer script. It's working fine on my Hostinger account, but when I move it over to my company's FatCow server it stops working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

The code is:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->IsSendmail();
$email->From        = "stuart@ubrew.cc";
$email->FromName    = "Stuart";
$email->Subject     = "Subject...";
$email->Body        = "text";  // BODY TEXT HERE
$email->AddAddress("$customeremail");

$email->AddAttachment($certificateName, 'GiftCertificate.pdf');

if (!$email->Send()) {
    $message = $email->ErrorInfo;
    mail('sewelly@gmail.com', 'MAILER ERROR', $message);
}
```

Comment: I believe so, I've successfully sent messages using mail() with the above info, sans the attachment

Comment: Have you enabled php error reporting, and if so, are there any errors?

Comment: I have error_reporting(E_ALL); set but it gives me nothing.

Comment: I just got an email with the following error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: `$email->AddAddress("$customeremail");` should not have quotes around the variable.  `$email->AddAddress($customeremail);`

Comment: Also, check out Salman A's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function

Comment: Thanks for that Devlin, unfortunately this hasn't worked, I'm now getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: the server error logs should have a detailed message regarding why the error 500 occurred.  do you have access to the logs?

Comment: You should read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide on GitHub.