# PHPMailer error: Could not instantiate mail function along with .txt file uploading

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to use `PHPMailer` (for the first time) in my project and I guess I have stuck.

What I am trying to achieve is upload the `.txt` file which contains the list of users' email address and extract that into an array and send them the mail. I want to use built in php `mail` function with the help of `PHPMailer`.

Here's the code that I have tried so far:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['btnSendMail'])) {    
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing E-Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Testing</h4>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
            <img src="http://www.example.in/images/unnamed-1.jpg" alt="Image" />
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>';


    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsMAIL();
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['emailFrom']);
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->msgHTML($message);

    $fp = fopen($_FILES['emailTxtFile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        $mail->addAddress($line);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    if (! $mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. <br /><br />';
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.in/testmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Email Subject"/>
    <input type="text" name="emailFrom" placeholder="From Email Address"/>
    <input type="file" name="emailTxtFile" />

    <input type="submit" name="btnSendMail" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I always end up getting error:

```
Message could not be sent. 

Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.
```

And the uploaded `.txt` file contains:

```
eamil-1@example.com
email-temp@example.com
exple@email.com
//... Can contain n number of email address...
```

I am pretty sure this must be a minor mistake that I am unable to locate.

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: comment out `/*$fp = fopen($_FILES['emailTxtFile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        $mail->addAddress($line);
    }
    fclose($fp);*/` and just do `$mail->addAddress("temp@example.com");`, obviously change the email address, and let us know what happens.

Comment: Nope.. Still the same error...

Comment: deleted my answer, no the space doesn't matter,Thought it did, sorry, thought I'd cracked it.......

Comment: are you on localhost ? I know xampp needs extra settings to send mail.

Comment: Nope.. Testing it on the server..

Comment: if you comment it all out and  just do `mail("someone@example.com","test subject","test message");`  does that work, obviously send yourself an email so change the email address

Comment: Yeah.. That does work without any issue..

Comment: Possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7145096/2746541

Comment: @MarioWerner Thanks for the link, but I have clearly said that I want to use PHP's built in mail function..

Comment: `mail()` operations are set in your php.ini - read the PHP docs.

Comment: been nosing through the docs, looking at possible solutions but am unable to test at the mo, setFrom looks like it takes 2 args, not sure if they're optional, the other thing i would try is commenting out the loop and hardcoding the values into all the fields,subject,from,to address and message in case the problem lies there, sorry can't help more.

Comment: It's okay.. I appreciate your help.. No issues.. Even I am scratching my head since 5 hours, but couldn't get it work.. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: @user3514160 PHP has no "built in mail function". It always uses the mail function of the operating system, which in most cases is `sendmail`. If you want to use `sendmail` thats ok. But you should at least test if it also works with SMTP.

Comment: Okay.. I will surely look into that for sure.. But can you please guide me how to incorporate SMTP host, username, password ? I am fairly new to this thing.. I have this website setup on shared hosting server..

Comment: How to setup `PHPMailer` to use `STMP` is shown in the link I posted you. You should get the specific SMTP settings in the backend of your hosting provider's customer panel. SMTP username is usually the full email address, like `jondoe@somedomain.com`