# PHP Mailer in Codeigniter Setfrom is not sending email to gmail,hotmail,ymail but setfrom is sending other custom business email to e.g abc@ab.com

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

mail is only sent when I used business email like(abc@abc.com) but when use gmail,Hotmail or yahoo mail it gives below error.

**Controller**

```
    $this->load->library("mailer");
    $mail = $this->mailer->load();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->IsMAIL();
    $mail->setFrom('ballers999@gmail.com', 'Ballers');
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();
```

error message could cot instantiate mail function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function

Comment: @SanjayKumar email is ok for custom domain but when i send it to someone gmail account it gives me this error could cot instantiate mail function

Comment: I understand your phpMailer call is using PHP mail function to send email. Check if you can send email using SMTP.

Comment: You can't send *from* a gmail address unless you're sending through gmail (i.e. not your local server, which is what `mail()` uses), otherwise it will fail SPF checks.