# I am getting "Could not instantiate mail function." when I use a domain name in subject or body

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

When I include test.com in the subject of an email the email fails to send. I am using phpmailer and office365

This fails:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    require '../../src/Exception.php';
    require '../../src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../../src/SMTP.php';
    //production Email
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "email@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "*********";
    $mail->setFrom('email@domain.com', 'reports');
    $mail->addAddress('email@domain.com', 'Name');

    $mail->Subject = "TEST.com";
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $body = "This is the body.";
    
    $mail->Body="$body"; //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);         //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';
    // $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file
    if(!$mail->send()){
        $display = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        $display = "Thank you for your submission! ";
    }
 ?>
```

This works: (the only difference is the a space between Test and .com)

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    require '../../src/Exception.php';
    require '../../src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../../src/SMTP.php';
    //production Email
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "email@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "*********";
    $mail->setFrom('email@domain.com', 'reports');
    $mail->addAddress('email@domain.com', 'Name');

    $mail->Subject = "TEST .com";
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $body = "This is the body.";
    
    $mail->Body="$body"; //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);         //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';
    // $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file
    if(!$mail->send()){
        $display = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        $display = "Thank you for your submission! ";
    }
 ?>
```

I have no idea after 8 hours of trying and retrying. I looked at Mail flow on EAC and there was nothing about the emails.

I tried everything from [Phpmailer error "Could not instantiate mail function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function) but it gets me this error (this includes adding $mail->isSMTP()):

```
2023-07-18 15:51:50 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-07-18 15:51:58 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection refused) [/home/hmktgroup/public_html/src/SMTP.php line 388]
2023-07-18 15:51:58 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function might help?

Comment: Your examples look identical to me?

Comment: @ADyson "This works: (the only difference is the a space between Test and .com)"

Comment: Yes, you already said that. But in both your samples, there is no space between Test and .com . So it's unclear what difference we are supposed to be observing.

Comment: `unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection refused)` ...hmm. You sure you don't have any outbound firewall rules preventing use of port 587 for outgoing traffic? Can you `telnet smtp.office365.com 587` from a command prompt on the same machine where the PHP code is running? If that connects, then there's no firewall issue.

Comment: I want to ensure I understand the question. You get "smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection refused)" when you do `$mail->Subject = "TEST.com"` but it works fine when you add a space between the domain components, being that the only difference? If that's the way it is, it totally looks like an overzealous security tool (antivirus, firewall, whatever).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think you are correct. I have eliminated office365 by using another STMP and my personal email. I am thinking it might be a go-daddy firewall issue.

Comment: You can't think Alvaro is correct, _and_ think it's a firewall issue. Those are two entirely different issues.

Comment: @ADyson How so? Alvaro said "overzealous security tool (antivirus, firewall, whatever)."

Comment: @JustinPhenix Apologies I missed the "firewall" bit of the remark, my bad. And I was thinking of something filtering on the O365 end of the process, rather than your local machine. You're right, those are not opposing possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You've gone to great effort to set SMTP properties, but have not actually told PHPMailer to use SMTP, so it's ignoring all those settings and falling back to `mail()` delivery through your local mail server, which doesn't appear to exist or is broken in some way. Presumably this is not what you intended. Try adding this:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

Comments following your question suggest that you might have added this, but now you're getting `connection refused` errors, which most likely suggests that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, in which case you need to [read the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host) on that subject.